# Conditional logic jsx react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to apply more than 1 condition to className in my jsx view. However it won't let me.

It only listens to the first condition.

```
className={usernameFocus ? "toggled" : "" || usernameValidated ? "validated" : ""}
```

I have tried several combinations:

```
className={usernameFocus ? "toggled" : "" + usernameValidated ? "validated" : ""}
```

How could I accomplish more than one conditional to add classNames to my element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of operations is mixed up. Put your separate conditions in parentheses. Also, you can short-circuit the class evaluation like this:

```
className={(usernameFocus && "toggled") + " " + (usernameValidated && "validated")}
```

If you feel extra fancy, you can also use a template string:

```
className={`${usernameFocus && "toggled"} ${usernameValidated && "validated"}`}
```

If you do this a lot (multiple booleans), have a look at the officially recommended `classnames` module by Jed Watson. [Link](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).

With it, you can do it like this:

```
var usernameClasses = classNames({
  'validated': usernameValidated,
  'toggled': usernameFocus
});

className={usernameClasses};
```

Comment: if usernameValidated is false, but usernameFocus is true, wouldn't that return "toggled false" ?

Comment: Correct. Unless you specify `false` to be an actual class though this should not be an issue. It makes the code a little cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a space between the class names for when both are applied, also brackets help with multiple nested conditional statements.

Try this:

```
className={(usernameFocus ? "toggled" : "") + " " + (usernameValidated ? "validated" : "")}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend the use of variables instead of doing inline logic in the attribute.